# How to convert Tableau to Circuit in stim

Tags: random-quantum-circuit, stim

I am trying to simulate random Clifford circuit. I can use stim.Tableau.random(n) to generate it, but don't know how to convert into stim.Circuit() form. It seems current v1.9 does not have to_circuit() function.

Answer (score 2):

Since stim v1.10 you can use [`stim.Tableau.to_circuit`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Tableau.to_circuit) to convert a tableau to a circuit. It won't be the maximum efficiency circuit, but it will be a correct circuit. An example:

```
import stim
tableau = stim.Tableau.random(4)
print(repr(tableau))

circuit = tableau.to_circuit(method="elimination")
print(circuit.diagram())

assert stim.Tableau.from_circuit(circuit) == tableau
```

The random tableau that came out when I ran the code:

```
stim.Tableau.from_conjugated_generators(
    xs=[
        stim.PauliString("+YYX_"),
        stim.PauliString("-Y_XZ"),
        stim.PauliString("+XZXY"),
        stim.PauliString("+Z_Y_"),
    ],
    zs=[
        stim.PauliString("+YYZX"),
        stim.PauliString("+XYZY"),
        stim.PauliString("-ZYY_"),
        stim.PauliString("-XX_X"),
    ],
)
```

And the generated circuit:

```
q0: -X-@-X-S-H-@-@-@---X-X-X-------------------------------H-S-S-----H-S-S-
     | | |     | | |   | | |
q1: -@-X-@---S-X-|-|-H-@-|-|-X-@-X-S-H-S-@-----------------H---S-S---H-----
                 | |     | | | | |       |
q2: -------------X-|-----@-|-|-|-|-----H-X-X-@-X-S-H-S-X---H-----S-S-H-----
                   |       | | | |         | | |       |
q3: ---------H-----X-------@-@-X-@---------@-X-@-----H-@-S-H-H-----S-S-H---
```

As you can see, the "elimination" method is going out of its way to not use anything exception H, S, CX. And also it is not attempting to make a shallow circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By the way, this there any way to define a gate(so that I can append this random gate directly)? Or append circuits on specific qubits(in this case, the "gate circuit" has a smaller size than the full circuit)?

Comment: @YuchengHe Stim has no concept of defining a custom gate for a circuit. There's also no built-in method for transforming which qubits the circuit operates on. You'll have to write that yourself by iterating over the operations and transforming them individually.